# How to create events in c#

Tags: c#, events

ok I have create a chessboard with this code:

```
int numBlocks = 8;
Panel[,] chessBoardPanels = new Panel[numBlocks, numBlocks];
for (int iRow = 0; iRow < numBlocks; iRow++)
    for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < numBlocks; iColumn++)
    {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        //set size
        p.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        //set back colour
        p.BackColor = (iRow + (iColumn % 2)) % 2 == 0 ? Color.Black : Color.White;
        //set location
        p.Location = new Point(50 * iRow, 50 * iColumn);
        chessBoardPanels[iRow, iColumn] = p;
        groupBox1.Controls.Add(p);
    }
```

When i use the command:

```
 chessBoardPanels[1,1].BackColor=Color.Red;
```

the panel changes color like it should  but then how would I create an event like mouse enter using the array?????

Comment: "create an event like mouse enter **using the array**" I have no idea what that even means

Comment: winforms i guess? If you use buttons and want to have a click event: `Button b = new Button();` `b.Click += b_Click;` and the handler: `void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ // etc. }` if it is webforms, I would use jQuery to have a hover/mouse-enter thing

Comment: Winforms? WPF? You can add a mouseover event to the form and check for collision based in x,y coords or if your Panel object has a graphix context then have each Panel check for mouseover events.

Comment: Ok a control has events which can be set like mouseOver, mouseEnter etc...sorta like a button click even when I try setting the event like chessBoardPanels[1,1] it won't let me create the click event

Comment: I think he wants to attach a click event to each panel in the array.

Comment: "setting the event like chessBoardPanels[1,1]" makes *no* sense. Post the code that you're having problems with, and try to explain clearly and concisely what you're trying to do.

Comment: But is it winforms, wpf or webforms? And the comments in the code are not needed.

Comment: ok i have already posted the code I am trying to use but how do I create a mouse enter event on each of the panels like:                 chessBoardPanels[1,1]_mouseEnter event

Comment: Yes, Amy i think you have the idea of what i am trying to accomplish.  Basically I have a 8 x 8 grid of panels which end up being chessBoardPanels[8,8]  but i would like to add events like mouse enter and mouse leave events

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the event to each `Panel` object you're generating, here's a rough sample of what I'm talking about

```
for (int iRow = 0; iRow < numBlocks; iRow++)
{
    for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < numBlocks; iColumn++)
    {
        Panel p = new Panel();

        // set size, position, etc, then:

        p.MouseEnter += (s,e) => { (s as Panel).BackColor=Color.Red; }
        p.MouseLeave += (s,e) => { (s as Panel).BackColor=Color.Black; }

        // the panel is born of this color
        p.BackColor = Color.Black; // .. or any color you put in MouseLeave
        groupBox1.Controls.Add(p);  
    }
}
```

Each `Panel` will have its own handlers for mouse entering/exiting it this way, and can be handled.